# Outlook 365 for Mac: missing FROM: field

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, office365

Recently we switched to Microsoft 365 as our email service provider. Later we created some aliases to our principle email address. On Outlook Web or Outlook for Windows I can activate "From" field easily and therefore send an email using an alias as sender.

However, on Outlook for Mac OSx, for some reasons I cannot find or activate the "From" option so can send only from a principle email address. How do I active "From" option in Outlook for Mac just as I can do on Outlook for Windows in order to send using an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, the FROM field will only display if you have more than 1 account configured in the profile. And it seem that Outlook for Mac does not support sending an email using an alias as sender like Outlook for Windows so far. We could only send emails from email accounts in the current profile.

Comment: Thanks, just got off the chat with MS support and they confirm that aliases don't work on Outlook for Mac. I ended up setting up sharedmailbox for Mac users.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your Google or Microsoft account with the alias name and it will add it as a separate account which you can use accordingly.

I did this and it works in the Outlook for Mac Version 16.46 (21 02 2021)

Answer (score 0):

found a way, head to settings, click on account, click on delegates and then under open these additional accounts, input the email name there and save. then click on new email, from should appear immediately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook for Mac 16.76, I followed what @kalejaiye suggested and I was able to enable the FROM field by adding to Outlook a second email account (in your case it would be the alias, in my case it was a functional email internal to my Institution).

Hit `Settings` -> `Accounts`. Select the main email account that the alias refers to. Then hit `Advanced` to see the advanced settings. Open the tab `Delegates` and add the alias to the list under `Open these additional mailboxes`.

You will then see the new alias account listed in the left-hand accounts tab. Then, when sending an email, you will be able to select the account to send it from.